# Angular2 Problems with service class and switchmap

Tags: json, http, angular

I'm currently having some problems with Angular 2. I'm used to create a detail view to one of my database components.

So far everything was good. My JSON Service is delivering the data as expected. 
When I console.log my result from within the subscribe function it seems okay, but the template crashes saying "can't read from undefined..."

Here is the source code:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from "@angular/router";
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import {ComponentTypeService} from "./component-type.service";
import {ComponentType} from "./database_objects";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'component-type-detail',
  templateUrl: 'component-type-detail.component.html'
})

export class ComponentTypeDetailComponent implements OnInit{
  componentType: ComponentType;
  constructor(
    private componentTypeService: ComponentTypeService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => this.componentTypeService.getComponentTypeDetails(+params['id']))
        .subscribe(comp => {
          this.componentType = comp;
          console.log(comp);
        });
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

Here is the service Code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ComponentType} from "./database_objects";
import {Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class ComponentTypeService{
  private baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/myFirstApp/component-types/'

  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  getComponentTypes(): Promise<ComponentType[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().results as ComponentType[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getComponentTypeDetails(id: number): Promise<ComponentType>{
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}${id}/`;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as ComponentType)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

[Error Stack in Browser. Please look at the bottom. The object is defined in line 31 it is inside the subscribe function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2qCj.png)

### UPDATE

Thanks to all your answers. It was the template missing a *ngIf="componentType"
here is the updated template:

```
<div *ngIf="componentType">
  <h2>{{componentType.component_type_name}} details!</h2>
  <div>
    <label>id: </label>{{componentType.id}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>name:</label>
    <!--<input [(ngModel)]="componentType.component_type_name" placeholder="name" />-->
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="componentType.components">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let component of componentType.components">
        {{component}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: template code ?

Comment: your template is being compiled before `ngOnInit` and your `componentType: ComponentType;` is undefined at initial level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your template is trying to access the object before its defined.

One of the solutions you have is wrapping the template code in `<template [ngIf]="yourObject"></template>`.

Another solution is to add an `*ngIf` everywhere you try to access a property of the object.

I prefer the first.